# Mixing JSON with normal data in cURL request in bash

Tags: json, bash, curl

I know I can use

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://hostname/resource
```

or

```
curl --request POST https://$url?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

But what do I need to do if param1 is value and param2 is a JSON?

It just does not work(tm) if I just toss the JSON in there, even using a variable

```
$json='{"data":"value"}'
curl --request POST https://$url?param1=value1&param2=$json
```

What is the trick here?
Note that I HAVE TO make only one call.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what it is that does not work? Do you get an error? Does the data not arrive at the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if we escape everything (using python) here's what it looks like

```
>>> x
'{"data": "value"}'
>>> urllib.urlencode({'param1':'value1', 'param2':x})
'param2=%7B%22data%22%3A+%22value%22%7D&param1=value1'
```

Or, using the curl option

```
curl localhost:8080 --data-urlencode 'param1={"data":"value"}'
```

Will send to the server

```
param1=%7B%22data%22%3A%22value%22%7D
```

You may notice that the first version has a +, which probably comes from the space in the json encoded, not sure it works or if it can be removed

Comment: Yes, the trick is to url-encode the whole JSON. I am using another way to do that but your idea is correct.